# turn on Cycles GPU render on non CUDA computers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, network

Is there a way to turn on GPU rendering without an installed CUDA driver and without a CUDA enabled graphic card?

I want to send the blend file on my render farm, all the slaves have NVidia CUDA cards, but I don't want to turn on my big computer just to set the blend file to GPU compute and then send it into my farm.

I'm modelling on my Surface Pro 3 [windows 8, i5-processor] on the go [works fine by the way :3], and when I am home I dispatch the jobs to the far, but this way they only work with the GPU when I turn on my greater Computer to change it there.

There doesn't have to be a way, but it would be nice if there were.

Comment: [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5281/blender-sets-compute-device-cuda-but-doesnt-use-it-for-actual-render-on-ec2) could probably help.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do it is to run this in a command line (or put it in a batch file). It enables Blender OpenCL test.

```
set CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST=all
"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe"
```

Then, in Blender's settings, head over to the "System" tab, and enable OpenCL.

[image: OpenCL in settings]

Reference: http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?302079-Blender-Cycles-AMD-Opencl-It-s-possible-working-now

Comment: Not sure but i think the experimental feature render option also enables OpenCL GPU rendering.