# No CUDA and GPU option

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have Blender 2.73a with AMD Radeon 3100 Graphics. I saw [this page](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/) on how to make cycles render faster. It says when I go to User Preferences> System> Compute Device, It has no CUDA option, which means there is no GPU option. How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure your graphics drivers are up to date and that it is compatible with Blender, just because you have a graphics card doesn't mean it will work.

Comment: Just used the OpenCL steps.

Comment: Does it show up on older versions of Blender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA is only available for nvidia GPUs. AMD cards can use openCL (Disabled in official builds).

Here is the wiki page on it http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/GPU_Rendering

Comment: read this to activate GPU OpenCL rendering : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/turn-on-cycles-gpu-render-on-non-cuda-computers/26195#26195