# can I run Blender for MacBookPro(Iris Pro broadwell) in this machine

Tags: compatibility

I plan to get a new MacBook Pro Retina 15" Broadwell with Iris Pro graphics card (Not dedicated) in the Summer 2015, can I run Blender for Mac in this machine?

Comment: Blender has no feet. Therefore, it cannot run. But, puns aside, Blender will fly quite well on your system. (It does have wings).

Answer (score 2):

Blender will work for sure, even on a computer without a dedicated Nvidia GPU .

Cylces rendering on GPU might be limited. You will need to enable *experimental* features to work on OpenCl.

To enable OpenCL read [turn on Cycles GPU render on non CUDA computers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/turn-on-cycles-gpu-render-on-non-cuda-computers/26195#26195)

Comment: also what display size you recommend? and can work in two displays MacBookPro15" retina + 23" HD 1920 x 1080 ... ?