# Headless render: can't find compute_device in 2.78b

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, rendering, scripting, gpu

On Ubuntu 16.04 (used as a headless renderer with dual GTX 970 STRIX GPUs) after upgrading to blender 2.78b I'm now seeing:

```
$ blender -b Lightsaber.blend -o //Lightsaber-tst-1_ -E CYCLES -F PNG -x 1 -P cuda0.py -f 1
AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "pulse"
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
read blend: /home/shady/usermaatre/School/Lightsaber.blend
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shady/usermaatre/School/cuda0.py", line 4, in <module>
    bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
```

The `cuda0.py` script is simple (it comes from [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?371076-Multiple-Blender-processes-for-multiple-GPUs)):

```
$ cat cuda0.py 
import bpy, _cycles

bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'

# this is different in each cuda[x].py file, CUDA_0, CUDA_1, CUDA_2, CUDA_3
bpy.context.user_preferences.system.compute_device = 'CUDA_0'
```

I had been running `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run` and `cuda_7.5.18_linux.run` so we tried upgrading to the latest `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run` and `cuda_8.0.61_375.26_linux.run` but that did not help.

I figured maybe the CUDA card has been renamed, so I tried running the script at  [How do I get Cycles to use GPU on a linux server?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70120/how-do-i-get-cycles-to-use-gpu-on-a-linux-server) and I get a similar result:

```
$ blender -b -P compute_device_type.py 
AL lib: (WW) alc_initconfig: Failed to initialize backend "pulse"
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1029:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steven/usermaatre/School/compute_device_type.py", line 7, in <module>
    devt = sysp.compute_device_type
AttributeError: 'UserPreferencesSystem' object has no attribute 'compute_device_type'

Blender quit
```

I'm thinking that something has changed in the naming of the card? Is there a simple way to determine the card attributes? And should the 8.0 drivers work on a headless system or should I go back to 7.5? I'd really rather not have to drop back to 2.78a which had worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the 2.78b, it's necessary to recover them via the preferences of the Cycles addon.
You cant get it with

```
bpy.context.user_preferences.addon['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type
```

And for the devices:

```
for card in bpy.context.user_preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.devices:
    print(card.name)
```

Comment: Also of note - `compute_device_type` is an enum - so if you try `compute_device_type = 'XXX'` you will get a *TypeError message* that lists the valid enum values.

Comment: @sambler @pistiwique Thanks, I get `enum "XXX" not found in ('NONE', 'CUDA')` so setting  `prefs.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'` works and both cards are used. I would also like to be able to address GPU0 & GPU1 separately, but `prefs.compute_device = 'CUDA_0'` fails.

Comment: I haven't tested this but it appears that the devices list shown in the above loop, is what you use to enable/disable devices. Set `compute_device_type = 'CUDA'` and then use `addons['cycles'].preferences.devices[0].use = False` to disable the first device and `devices[1]` for the second. Each device has id, name, type and use properties.

Comment: @sambler thanks - `prefs.devices[0].use = False` worked! The above loop printed out `<bpy_struct, CyclesDeviceSettings("GeForce GTX 970")>` twice but I was not able to determine the deeper structure. How did you determine to set `.use = False` (where the old way was `.compute_device = 'CUDA_0'`)? I wonder what other options might exist?

Comment: I used the source @ShadyPuck ;) - You can find CyclesDeviceSettings defined in [properties.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/blender/addon/) inside the cycles addon. I expect this is a simpler approach to controlling the many variations of different devices. It has just been added so expect more changes to come.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this method doesnt work with 2.79?
I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'UserPreferences' object has no attribute 'addon'`

Edit:
Got it working!    a stupid missing 's'

Here is the working script i'm using to force the worker station to use all cuda devices:

```
import bpy
bpy.context.user_preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'
bpy.context.user_preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device = 'CUDA_MULTI_2'
```